# Input an ordered list of values in an HTML form

Tags: html, forms, list, user-experience

How can I create an HTML form for which the user indicates a **list** of values drawn from a set of values? I can provide the form with the set of values to choose from.

The user is not indicating a *set* of values: the order of the selected values is important (the values are to be in descending priority order).

It would seem that the [`multiple` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-multiple-attribute) on a [`select` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element) would be useful. But the `select` element does not seem to have any means for indicating the order of the selections, nor does the POST of the form guarantee ordering of the selected values.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you want but you can try the [*HTML5 sortable*  plugin](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/), which is now hosted on [github](https://github.com/voidberg/html5sortable).

It's as simple as an `<ul>` with a list of elements and the user drag and drop the elements. With the callback

```
  $('.sortable').sortable().bind('sortupdate', function() {
     //Triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM position has changed.
  });
```

And you can read the elements in the correct order and make that you want with it (save to DB, etc).

Comment: That JQuery code seems to handle the UX side. But what about the POST of the data?

Comment: With the callback.... You can send the data as you want or as you like. And yes, the project is in a new page but is the same. No jQuery needed.

Comment: I use this to reorder the products on a shop, and it works really fine. On sortupdate, you can read all elements in the correct order with a simple loop (`$.each()` can be useful) and then send it.

Comment: However, this post is too broad or primary opinion based, because there are tons of different solutions, all are good, but it is based on a subjective opinion.

Comment: vanilla js option?